# Change HTTP authentication password in Gerrit

Tags: apache, gerrit, basic-authentication

I am using HTTP way of authentication for gerrit (apache is authenticating on gerrit's behalf). I have a file in my apache folder which contains username:encrypted password. I am currently able to login using this configuration, however, how will a user change this password using the UI (which is to be changed on first login)?

Answer (score 0):

Using that setup is not ideal for a production environment. You either want to change to LDAP or OpenID or use Apache HTTP auth against some other user database (you are pretty flexible there, search [the list of modules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/) for *auth*).

If you really don't have anything to authenticate against, well.. then you manage your users in that htpasswd file. With HTTP auth, there is no way to change the password through the Gerrit UI.

Comment: I have configured Gerrit to be used with LDAP and it's working fine. However, I don't see a way how the user can change his/her password, if he/she wishes to?

Comment: Gerrit does afaik not support changing the LDAP password. You have no interface for your user to change the LDAP password? In doubt I would recommend [GOsa](https://oss.gonicus.de/labs/gosa).